# Drupal 6 vs Drupal 7 performance

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Drupal 7 slower than Drupal 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908736/is-drupal-7-slower-than-drupal-6)

I want to start new project and stuck without idea what version to use.

I have huge expirience with D6, and also one project (module developement) for D7. It looks like D7 slower, have bigger memory consumption and also have a lack of documentation by the moment. I don't need new CCK, Views and other - looks like I'll coding all features needed as modules.

Is D7 have sweet parts now, or better way is develop project under D6?

What way you choose for yourself, and why?

Comment: berkes, thanks, I read this before ask my question, but it is NOT answer. I don't need CCK and other. I don't mentioned page generation speed because of cache. I need to know other pros and cons too (PDO included, new nice separation for blocks and nice theming layer). It is not question about raw speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the developer or themer point of view however, I love Drupal 7 because, there are quite a few key improvements, such as:

- Core support of `translatable Fields without localization hell` like in the previous versions (which is helpful both to module and theme developers)
- Being able to have `vocabularies with fields`
- Being able to give users access to the `nodes list page without having to give full node edition rights` (or installing a bunch of additional modules).

---

I liked the eye-candy and technical feat of the overlayed interface, however personally I prefer turning that off: too confusing for regular users and my minimalisation instinct cringes at the sight of overlapping pages.

The only downside to D7 right now is that, depending on your needs, there may be some modules that haven't migrated yet, but that won't take long, especially if you make your own modules (which is something you mentionned in the question).

Comment: By the way, the Drupal-specialized section of Stackoverflow (http://drupal.stackexchange.com) has open its beta a few days ago, it may be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7's obvious benefit is the overlayed ajaxified admin interface - it's no longer theme dependant, and the menus are WAY easier to navigate. This is HUGE for Drupal. the APIs follow suit, the changes are very nice to work with.

That said, a large part of the modules available for Drupal 7 (even those supposedly converted) are not 100% yet, so if you're looking to get something quick and stable up, then Drupal 6 is for you.

Two examples:

- I was setting up a photography site for a friend who wanted to sell photos immediately and manage orders; I used Drupal 6 because when I tried D7's Ubercart port it was barely functional and left warnings/errors all over the place.
- My girlfriend wanted a site to showcase her photos in an image gallery but not sell them, and do some basic blog stuff (she might expand later); this I could do myself without relying on other modules, so I used Drupal 7 and it worked out great. She has a much easier time working with D7, largely in part of the shortcuts menu overlay it has built in.

So Drupal 7 is easier, but Drupal 6 has rock solid support for add-ons and such.

Give it 6 months to a year and Drupal 7 will catch up.

Comment: The admin theme is ported back to Drupal6 http://drupal.org/project/seven, so that is no argument.

Answer (score -2):

Drupal 7 is bulky then D6. D7 produce large quantity of  and I think that D7 is slower then D6 in term of speed n performance